# Angular/Typescript - Event, change number with constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor

I'm new to Angular and TypeScript, hence the following question and my approach in general might be stupid:

I'm currently working on a bootstrap carousel with a previous & next arrow. To make it work, my first and yet only intention was to create an event. The event for my prev-arrow calls the constructor "prevClick()". I declared a variable and a property called "imagePath" which I'm going to call later in HTML via property binding. Now everytime the arrow is clicked, i shall be increased or decreased by one (if i is 1, it shall jump to the last image, which is image3). According to Augury this works just fine and i is changing with every click - but somehow the i inside of the path isn't.

Do you have any suggestion or is there a better approach?

```
export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {

      i = 1;

      imagePath = 'assets/images/image' + this.i + '.jpg';


      prevClick() {
        if (this.i === 1) {
          this.i = this.i + 2;
        } else {
          this.i = this.i - 1;
        }
      }
```

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the rest of your code would be helpful, especially the template, I believe what is desired is for `imagePath` to dynamically update with the new value of `i`.

All you need to do is make a small update to the definition of `imagePath` so that at least that portion of the code behaves properly. Note this will not achieve animation, so that is a separate problem (and one which probably won't be solved by this approach at all).

```
get imagePath(): string {
  return `assets/images/image${this.i}.jpg`;  // use of string interpolation recommended
}
```

For what it's worth, I would also recommend refactoring your functions. You also *should* get in the habit of fully declaring signatures (note the `: void` at the end).

```
increment(): void {
  this.i = (i === this.maxVal ? this.minVal : i + 1);
}

decrement(): void {   
  this.i = (i === this.minVal ? this.maxVal : i - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because strings are immutable. You will need to manually update your `imagePath` inside `prevClick()`.

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgzyg2

component.ts:

```
  public i: number = 1;
  public example = `Angular ${this.i}`;

  onClick(inc: number) {
    this.i += inc;
    this.i = this.i < 0 ? 0 : this.i;

    this.example = `Angular ${this.i}`;
  }
```

component.html:

```
<button (click)='onClick(1)'>up</button>
<button (click)='onClick(-1)'>down</button>
```

Comment: What does immutable strings have to do with this?

Comment: @JuanMendes It means that the string won't automatically update when `i` is changed - even though you can use string interpolation (which would make you think it would seeing as so much angular stuff is data bound and auto-magically updated on value changes).

Comment: @Zze Thanks! Your approach definitely helped! The only problem was, that i was continuously decreasing into negativity.

Comment: @ZZe that doesn't make sense, this would not happen even in an environment where strings are mutable, like in C. You'd have to re-evaluate the expression anyway. -1 until you remove or add better explanation

Answer (score 0):

There is a little issue here and that being when you set `imagePath` up there it stays like that even if the `i` value is changing. you should add a piece of code like following and call it each time you update `i` value.

```html
 updateImageName(){
       this.imagePath = 'assets/images/image' + this.i + '.jpg';
      }
```

```html
    prevClick() {
        if (this.i === 1) {
          this.i = this.i + 2;
        } else {
          this.i = this.i - 1;
        }

        this.updateImageName();
      }
```

This way you will always have the `imagePath` with the updated `i` value.